# I want to be able to compile and program from school from a thumbdrive, what would be the best language for this?

Tags: compiler-construction, usb, portability

I have a lot of spare time during my classes, and I want to do something constructive during this period. So I was wondering if anyone could recommend a programing language that I can learn during my free time that I can compile from a portable compiler.

The school is a Microsoft environment, using Windows XP 32bit.

Edit: Hillbilly Typos, woops.

Comment: [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is portable; just unzip the file and you're off to the races. The advantage is you don't have to suffer through a terrible IDE, poor UI, or learn a language you won't ever have any use for.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. I still have to wait till I get home as they only have installers for windows, but this looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Download portable eclipse and install pretty much any compiler plugin for it. Java would be a natural choice if you'r only starting out.. (also supports c/c++, php, python... and a bunch of other)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's possible to install Cygwin on a thumb drive, and with that you can use your language of choice, whether it's compiled (ie, C++) or interpreted (ie, Python).

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible (with just a bit of tweaking cygwin.bat). But MinGW will be a more compact choice.